# Regex that does not allow consecutive dots

Tags: regex

I have a Regex to allow alphanumeric, underscore and dots but not consecutive dots:

```
^(?!.*?[.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$
```

I also need to now allow dots in the first and last character of the string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use it like this with additional lookaheads:

```
^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$
```

- `(?!\.)` - don't allow `.` at start
- `(?!.*\.\.)` - don't allow 2 consecutive dots
- `(?!.*\.$)` - don't allow `.` at end

Comment: just want to point out that this can be written shorter like `^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[\w.]+$`

Comment: Yes indeed `\w` is shortcut for `[[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in many regex flavors but not supported in awk, sed etc.

Comment: And to disallow string starting with a digit, I added `(?!\d)` to make the regex: `^(?!\d)(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$`. Thanks for the breakdown of each regex portion. :)

Comment: @anubhava Do we need to use it like this `$number = '.5'; $numberCheck = preg_match("/^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)+$/", $number); echo $numberCheck;` because I get every time 0 result.

Comment: Yes, it returns 0. I would like to not allow more than one (dot) to be placed on the written numbers. Also, I don't want to put (dots) or (dots) at the beginning or the end. for example user can not post `.01 or .1 or something like started dot` also user can not post `11. or 1.` the number 1 is just an example I just want to allow user to post numbers with dot.

Comment: But this regex already doesn't allow `11.` or `.11`

Comment: @anubhava But if you check this code `$number = '1.5'; 

$numberCheck = preg_match("/^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/", $number); 

echo $numberCheck;` in phptester.net website you can see the result is not correct. The result must be 1.5 but it is showing 1

Comment: use `preg_match("/^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/", $number, $m);` and them print `$m[0]`

Comment: I am using this regex in android but still allowing dot at the start

Answer (score 3):

Re-write the regex as

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$
```

or (in case your regex flavor is ECMAScript compliant where `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

```
^\w+(?:\.\w+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPIonI/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`  - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` - 1 or more word chars
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$
```

This will not allow any consecutive dots in the string and will also allow dot as first and last character

[Tried here](https://regex101.com/r/8UT9A6/1)