# regex to find and avoid double dots in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to find double dots, if consecutive double dot exits in any email it should prompt me with "NO"

```
DECLARE 
v_email webowner.person.email%TYPE;
v_constant CONSTANT VARCHAR2(300) := '^(([a-zA-Z0-9"_\-])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/%+="''\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])@(\[((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}|((([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,}|(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\]))$';
BEGIN
  v_email := 'test_sample@mercer.com';
if regexp_like(v_email, v_constant) then

  pl('YES: ' || v_email);
else
  pl('NO: ' || v_email);
end if;
END;
```

Note: Double dot means consecutive dots and presence of double dots needs to be checked before "@"

Tried using [Regex that does not allow consecutive dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718851/regex-that-does-not-allow-consecutive-dots#new-answer?newreg=df136a05cb074e59bd7254586c076db4)

Could not find the proper placement of regex.

Kindly help.

Comment: Are you certain that you even want to allow double dots _anywhere_ ?

Comment: Replace `([a-zA-Z0-9"_\-])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/%+="''\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])` with [`[a-zA-Z0-9"_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_/%+="''-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*`](https://regex101.com/r/NW3Cxe/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/%+="''\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

To this:

```
((\.?[a-zA-Z0-9_\/%+="''\-]+)*\.?[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

So basically, if there are any dots to match, they must be interspersed with some number of non-dot, acceptable characters. That way you will never match two consecutive ones.

Comment: Request you to look into Question No. 47416137

Answer (score 1):

My immediate idea is just to check if the index of ".." is less than the index of "@", and that the first index is not -1.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN INSTR(v_email, '..') BETWEEN 1 AND INSTR(v_email, '@') - 1
         THEN 'dots present'
         ELSE 'no dots' END AS dots
FROM yourTable;
```

I hope this is of help to you :)