# Regular expression for non ASCII as well as for ASCII characters oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

Referring: [regex to find and avoid double dots in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888125/regex-to-find-and-avoid-double-dots-in-oracle)

I have a requirement, to check for presence non ASCII characters as well as ASCII characters (NON ASCII characters may or may not be there).

For ASCII character(email validation), below results in True

```
DECLARE 
v_email varchar2(100);
v_constant CONSTANT VARCHAR2(300) := '^(([a-zA-Z0-9_"\-])([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/%+="''\-]*)@(\[((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}|((([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,}|(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\]))$';

BEGIN
  v_email := 'sample.test2@oracle.com';
if regexp_like(v_email, v_constant) then

  pl('YES: ' || v_email);
else
  pl('NO: ' || v_email);
end if;
END;
```

In case for Non ASCII characters for email validation below results in True:

```
DECLARE 
v_email varchar2(100);
v_constant CONSTANT VARCHAR2(300) := '^(([a-zA-Z0-9_"\-])[^\p{Alpha} ]([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/%+="''\-]*)@(\[((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}|((([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,}|(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\]))$';

BEGIN
  v_email := 'sämple.test2@oracle.com';
if regexp_like(v_email, v_constant) then

  pl('YES: ' || v_email);
else
  pl('NO: ' || v_email);
end if;
END;
```

But now I have a scenario where I have to merge both the conditions, it is not compulsory that email must have NON ASCII characters (it can or can't have ASCII characters. but if Non ASCII character is there it must be before **@** at any position).

Kindly help me with the regular expression which can check for either of the scenario and result me true.

Comment: Why merge both conditions? Why not just use two regular expressions?

Comment: Since I have to validate email's related to these type of scenario so until its code restriction, I need to handle both scenario in a single reg exp.