# Restrict dot on empty input field

Tags: angular, angular6

I have mat input field in angular 6 in which i am going to restrict (.)dot on empty field. if value presents dot needs allowed otherwise if empty input field means it should throw error like "dot not allowed'

how to achieve this in angular 6

anyone help me please...

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" class="full-width transparent-form">
    <input matInput name="hoursSpent" required #workedHoursValidation="ngModel"
           placeholder="Worked hours:e.g:1.5 (or) 1" class="w-100" appNumberAloneMask [form]="form"
           [ngModel]="newTaskHours" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" (ngModelChange)="newTaskHours = form.value.hoursSpent">
    <mat-error *ngIf="workedHoursValidation.hasError('required')">Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: you can get some help from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718896/6820850

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern (regex expression) validation on your form, here is an example:

> Validator that requires the control's value to match a regex pattern.
>   This validator is also provided by default if you use the HTML5
>   pattern attribute.

```
const myForm = new FormGroup(
  {
    'hoursSpent': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$')])
  }
);
```

You can find more information about angular validation [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) and specifically [pattern validation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern)